# pull to refresh in webView using webkit in swift 4

Tags: webview, webkit, ios9, swift4, pull-to-refresh

I'm already add pull to refresh function in my code, the icon refresh will appear when I start  pull it but when I had make changing in the webview such as tick the checkbox or enter the text in textbox,,why It not reset back to the default view?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)


        let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.facebook.com/")!
        let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)


        //activity indicator
        self.webView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.webView.navigationDelegate=self;


        //refresh
        webView.scrollView.bounces = true
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear( animated )

        let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.facebook.com/")!
        let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    @objc func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("refersh")
        //
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }


}
```

Comment: which part I need to add or change?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found a solution how the pull to refresh Indicator waits til the WebView did Finish loading:

I have used a UIRefreshControl instead an UIActivityIndicator.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController:     UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.google.com")!
    let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

    //refresh
    webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = .white
    let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "refreshing ...", attributes: attributes)
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    webView.scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear( animated )

    let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.google.com")!
    let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
  self.webView.scrollView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    self.webView.scrollView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}


func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@objc func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("refresh")
    self.webView.reload()
}
```